# Automatically browser gets closed while recording a travel website using Jmeter 4.0

Tags: jmeter, internet-explorer-11, jmeter-4.0

i have installed Jmeter 4.0 in my local machine.
i made some necessary changes for recording traffic using IE browser.
i want to record a travel website's scenario but while doing this my browser gets automatically shuts while recording.

I also tried that website's URL in trusted site mode. I'm still facing the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You question doesn't contain enough information so we cannot suggest exact steps to overcome the issue. If for any reason you need to continue using IE browser I would recommend checking the following:

- *jmeter.log* file. It is located in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation and normally contains enough information in order to guess where the problem is
- the reason of IE crash potentially can be discovered via [Event Viewer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938674.aspx)

---

Alternative recording options are in:

- Use [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) browser. It has its own [proxy configuration](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-settings-firefox) which is not using system-wide proxy settings so it might be more suitable for recording applications which require Internet access
- Use [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension). In this way you won't have to worry about proxies, SSL certificates, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my application can be accessible only on internet explorer.                                                                                         Jmeter log file error message :                                                                   Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'URL Name'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake